# IE < 9 showing displaying "Member not found"

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I am seeing the "SCRIPT3: Member not found." error in IE < 9 . Looking at various locations, (eg., [Member not found IE error (IE 6, 7, 8, 9)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531751/member-not-found-ie-error-ie-6-7-8)) it seems to occur at the `setTimeout` inside `.hover()` portion.

I followed the steps in the but still am having the same problem. I would be greatful for any help.

Probably it could also occur at places inside the `change()` fn.

I have placed the entire code at : http://jsfiddle.net/f4tZQ/

Comment: can you add your edit as an answer?

Comment: In jquery-1.6.2.js file, line 3172, I commented out        ` e.cancelBubble = true; `     and inserted 
      ` if (typeof e.cancelBubble !== 'unknown') { e.cancelBubble = true; } `       . In other words, a slight modification of the original jquery file.

Comment: Sorry. Wanted to add code : commented out - `e.cancelBubble = true;` and inserted - `if (typeof e.cancelBubble !== 'unknown') { e.cancelBubble = true; }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After sometime searching, I seems to be affected by jQuery bug. Following the "comment:4" , changing the jQuery-1.6.2.js file, line 3172 solved the problem.

```
if (typeof e.cancelBubble !== 'unknown') { e.cancelBubble = true; }
```

> Don't ask why, but it worked... For some reason jQuery or IE returns
>   'unknown' here in stead of 'undefined'.

Obtained from :

Source : http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10004

Comment: See my question for more information regarding "unknown" in IE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982739/typeof-returning-unknown-in-ie

Comment: Editing JQuery is a bad idea.

Answer (score 8):

For others who get here who don't want to modify the jQuery source...(FOR THE LOVE OF GOD DON'T DO THAT)

This happens in ie<9 when firing custom events. If you have access to the event before it gets to the point where ie crashes, just travel down the originalEvent chain and set the last one = {};

The below code is for when you are relying jQuery to process the event handlers return value (`false`) somewhere down the chain. If you want to cancel the event here, see the comments - wrap a call to `e.stopPropagation()` in a try/catch block

```
var handleAndFire = function(e) {
 var ev = new $.Event('stack.overflow');

    //you may have to debug and manually inspect to see how 
    //deep the originalEvents go
    //or you could write your own function to traverse 
    //depth first and find it automatically, I'm lazy.
    e.originalEvent.originalEvent = {}; //fix for ie < 9
    ev.originalEvent = e;
    $(document).trigger(ev);    
}
$(document).click(handleAndFire);
```

Comment: Nice. I found that modifying `e.originalEvent.originalEvent` broke the `stopPropagation()` call (no crash but also no propagation stopping) in my case which was the source of the crash in the first place. I solved the problem finally by wrapping the call in a try/catchall: `try { event.stopPropagation(); } catch (e) {}`

Comment: This is a great workaround for calling event.stopPropagation(), but doesn't help if you are returning false and letting jQuery do the stopping itself.