# typeof returning "unknown" in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, typeof

I have a window, where before being closed I refresh the underlying page.

```
if(opener && typeof(opener.Refresh) != 'undefined')
{
    opener.Refresh();
}
```

If I moved away from the original opening page, this code would throw a *"Permission Denied"* error.

Debugging the code revealed that `typeof(opener.Refresh)` was equal to *"unknown"* instead of the expected *"undefined"*.

As far as I'm aware *"unknown"* is not one of the return values for `typeof`, **so how and why would this value be returned?**

***Further Information***

I avoided the error by changing the check to:

```
if(opener && typeof(opener.Refresh) == 'function')
```

However examples like this ([detecting-an-undefined-object-property-in-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property-in-javascript)) do not seem to factor "unknown" into the equation.

Comment: It isn't declared, however the window is created with a standard window.open.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

According to a [duplicate question at Bytes](http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/515951-typeof-operator-returns-unknown-instead-undefined#post2009988), the typeof value `unknown` is added to JScript version 8, along with `date`.

A [comment](http://robertnyman.com/2005/12/21/what-is-typeof-unknown/#comment-8001) to a blog by Robert Nyman can also be explanatory:

> Internet Explorer displays “unknown” when the object in question is on
>   the other side of a COM+ bridge. You may not know this or realize
>   this, but MS’s XMLHTTP object is part of a different COM+ object that
>   implements IUnknown; when you call methods on it, you’re doing so over
>   a COM bridge and not calling native JavaScript.
>
> Basically that’s MS’s answer if you try to test or access something
>   that’s not a true part of the JScript engine.

Comment: Thanks. I had already seen that comment, however I couldn't relate it to my seemingly simple case...

Comment: So the best solution is to never check for `!== 'undefined'` and check that it equals one of the known values? Or use the `in` operator as [TomaszDz](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15152662/227299) suggested?

Comment: If you really need to check for undefined (and not function existence as OP edited above), then the following would work: (typeof myObj.myProp === 'undefined' || typeof myObj.myProp === 'unknown')

Comment: First JScript 8 doesn't exist; did you mean 5.8? Secondly how do you get `"date"` out of IE?

Answer (score 6):

The [ECMAScript specification](http://es5.github.com/#x11.4.3) states that for host objects the return value of the `typeof` operator is:

> Implementation-defined except may not be "`undefined`", "`boolean`",
>   "`number`", or "`string`".

I believe the `unknown` value is only ever returned in Internet Explorer. Interestingly, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/259s7zc1%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) does not mention it:

> There are six possible values that typeof returns: "number," "string,"
>   "boolean," "object," "function," and "undefined."

Comment: Do you have any ideas under what scenarios "unknown" would be returned?

Comment: No idea I'm afraid. I can't find any real documentation about it. That's the problem with host objects. There are no standards so the browser devs can pretty much do whatever they want.

Comment: @BrettPostin A whole lot of `typeof == 'unknown'` in [`window.external`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535246(v=vs.85).aspx) For example `typeof window.external.AutoScan` or `window.external.CreateAuthorizationHeader`

Comment: [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/typeof-operator-decrementjavascript) now mentions this.

Answer (score 6):

Try `in` operator. I had the same problem (with applet) and I solved it using `in`:

```
if("Refresh" in opener) {
    opener.Refresh();
}
```