# a simple syntax wonder: access html object by their global name under IE?

Tags: javascript, dom, internet-explorer-8

I access my DOM Objects this way:

#### HTML

```
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

#### JavaScript

```
alert(mydiv.style.visibility);
```

It works everywhere, smooth.
Now I've got a situation where, depending on some parameters, I remove some elements from the window (1 or 2):

#### JavaScript

```
if (condition) mydiv.parentNode.removeChild(mydiv);
```

And later on, still in the javascript code, I execute the part related to that element only if it exists:

#### JavaScript

```
if (mydiv) mydiv.style.whatever = "1";
```

This does not work under IE8, it returns "Object doesn't support this property or method"
I tried to check against `undefined` as well, with no success [**the part that crashes is the `if (mydiv)` part!**]

What is the best solution for this? I don't want to replace my code everywhere and check `document.getElementById("mydiv") == null`...

Comment: You may not want to use `getElementById()` but that is the correct standards-compliant way of doing it.

Comment: This is a very non-standard way of doing things, so here is an attempt at a non-standard solution... does `if (mydiv.height > 0) mydiv.style.properties = "value";` work for your example?

Comment: @RichardA., IE stops right at `mydiv`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to check for `style` property too?

```
if (mydiv && mydiv.style) mydiv.style.whatever = "1";
```

And can you show what `alert( typeof mydiv )` returns if node was deleted from DOM?

**EDIT:**

So if IE8 return `unknown` type for `typeof` operator this check should help:

```
if( typeof mydiv !== 'unknown' )
```

Comment: And what typeof mydiv?

Comment: Maybe this answer will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982739/typeof-returning-unknown-in-ie

Comment: I suppose this is not better than checking document.getElementById... Thank you for your input

Comment: plalx' answer is a correct answer since he focuses onto the standard. Like I explained in my last comment on his post, I'm prefering this approach (checking the type against unknown) for the moment.

Comment: @antyrat, Maybe you should change a bit your answer, since it doesn't solve the issue in any way in the way it is written write now. It doesn't reference `typeof mydiv` anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

First of all its an extremely bad practice to rely of globally created variables based on IDs, because that's not a standard.

However, you can always create the global variable yourself:

`var mydiv = document.getElementById('mydiv');`

Now, the fact that you are removing the element from the DOM doesn't mean that the object will be nullified. The `mydiv` variable still references a DOM object, which is simply not part of the DOM anymore.

Here's what you can do:

```
if (condition) {
    mydiv.parentNode.removeChild(mydiv);
    mydiv = null;
}
```

Now, `mydiv` will reference the `null` value and since `null` is a falsey value, it will do the trick when doing `if (mydiv)`

Comment: I see your point. Yet I don't feel like declaring a variable for each dom element I manipulate in javascript... Thank you very much for your input, it was useful.

Comment: @Sebas, well it's not how you feel about it, but how it should be done that is important. It's like saying to your boss that you did not feel like doing good work. That's not an option =P However, you can still assign `null` to `mydiv` in your case and it should work without having to declare the `mydiv` variable first.

 PS: If it solved your issue, please accept this answer. Thanks!

Comment: In the context of the website I am developping, accessing the objects by their id directly is extremely convenient. The cost of adding a **very** polluting global variable declaration for each element is now assumed and anticipated, for when webkit and mozilla decide to remove this undocumented "feature". For the moment, I am still pragmatic and prefer esthetics and readability. Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 0):

I beleive it's allways better to define a variable,

```
var mydiv = document.getElementById('mydiv');
```

but in your case you can use this as a workaround i guess:

```
if(typeof mydiv != 'undefined') if(mydiv.parentNode) mydiv.style.whatever = "1";
```