# WIA.Vector via Enumerator returns something which is not a number

Tags: javascript, activex, jscript, wia

When accessing the members of the WIA [**Vector** object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms630513(v=vs.85).aspx) directly using the **Vector**'s [**Item** property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms630523(v=vs.85).aspx), or using the default property, they are seen by JScript as numbers:

```
var v = new ActiveXObject('WIA.Vector');
v.SetFromString('This is a test', true, false);
for (var i = 1; i<= v.Count; i+=1) {
    WScript.Echo(String.fromCharCode(v(i)));
}
```

However, if I use an [**Enumerator**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff521216(v=vs.85).aspx) to iterate through the **Vector**:

```
var enumerator = new Enumerator(v);
enumerator.moveFirst();
while (!enumerator.atEnd()) {
    WScript.Echo(String.fromCharCode(enumerator.item()));
    enumerator.moveNext();
}
```

I get the following error under WScript / CScript:

> enumerator.item() is not a number

`typeof` returns `unknown`:

```
WScript.Echo(typeof enumerator.item());
```

Presumably it's some sort of Automation type (as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10982739/111794)) that only appears as a number, which is why `typeof` returns `unknown`.

**How can I coerce this value to a "real" Javascript number?**

---

**Update**

The following code in VBA:

```
Dim v As New Vector, item As Variant
v.SetFromString "This is a test", True, False
For Each item In v
    Debug.Print TypeName(item)
Next
```

prints

> Byte
>   Byte
>   ...

So the question can be narrowed down to the **Byte** specific Automation type.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me on IE11's console. (You have a mistake on the while loop)

The code:

```
console.log("- Vector -");
var v = new ActiveXObject('WIA.Vector');
v.SetFromString('This is a test', true, false);
for (var i = 1; i<= v.Count; i++) {
    console.log(v(i), String.fromCharCode(v(i)), typeof v(i));
}

console.log("- Enumerator -");
var e = new Enumerator(v);
e.moveFirst();
while (!e.atEnd()) {
    console.log(e.item(), String.fromCharCode(e.item()), typeof e.item());
    e.moveNext(); // You need this
}
```

Will print to the console:

```
- Vector -
84 T number
104 h number
105 i number
115 s number
32   number
105 i number
115 s number
32   number
97 a number
32   number
116 t number
101 e number
115 s number
116 t number
0  number
- Enumerator -
84 T number
104 h number
105 i number
115 s number
32   number
105 i number
115 s number
32   number
97 a number
32   number
116 t number
101 e number
115 s number
116 t number
0  number
```

Comment: How did you get this to work under IE? I get `Automation server can't create object`. In any event, this may work under IE, but it doesn't work under WScript / CScript.

Comment: The problem is not in the missing `.moveNext` call; if it was, the code would not error, it would continue in a never-ending loop.

Comment: Yes, I know the problem was not the moveNext, that is why I just said that it works for me (the missing moveNext just produce an infinite loop).
To execute it on IE, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15686040/ie9-automation-server-cant-create-object-error-while-using-certenroll-dll