# IE 10 run compatibity run as IE 8

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, registry, internet-explorer-10, ie-developer-tools

I am using IE 10.But some website has login problem in IE 10 but works in IE 8 . So in IE 10 i am using F12 developer tools and setting it to IE 8 compatibility. I think it can be set default to the browser by changing registry.There are so many articles on it in web.Below is some.
 [How to force IE10 to render page in IE9 document mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382636/how-to-force-ie10-to-render-page-in-ie9-document-mode)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730(v=vs.85).aspx

but for me it's not working or i am doing wrong. I also didn't understand what is contoso.exe mentioned in those.

So what exactly should i change if i want to open IE 10 in IE 8 compatibility. I am using 64 bit windows 8 pc

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem where it work on my local machine but not working on PROD server which made to think that my local machine might got an update from Microsoft and PROD server has not been updated.The app we are testing was doing good on IE compatibility mode but was getting all kinds of weird things in IE 10.I too had login problems when using IE10 but its doing fine in IE 8 ,IE 9 and IE 10 compatibility mode.
I asked to update the prod server with the hot fix which was released by Microsoft 2 years back. But my server has 2.0 framework on it , so i asked them to move to framework 3.5 and apply this fix . Now the app does function fine and I am able to use without changing the browser mode to IE 10 compatibility mode.
Here is the link for the fix
http://support.microsoft.com/hotfix/KBHotfix.aspx?kbnum=2600088&kbln=en-us