# how to run application in ie 10 mode when i m using ie 11

Tags: html, asp.net

my application is not working properly in IE11, it works fine in IE10 now few users are using ie 11, if they open my website in ie11 i want to make ie docmode 10  how to do it in html page

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to force IE10 to render page in IE9 document mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382636/how-to-force-ie10-to-render-page-in-ie9-document-mode)

Comment: Somewhat strange question - why do you want to force older version if it works in IE10 and IE11? Anyway you need to do exactly the same as you'd do for forcing IE9 with "X-UI-Compatible".

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: i want to do it only for ie 11 not for other doc modes, if any user opens site in 9 it should run in ie 9 mode only