# Visual Studio 2012 MVC Application Crashes in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

I'm having some issues getting my project to run in Internet Explorer. Everything works perfectly in Chrome, but when I start it in IE I get the following error message.

```
Unhandled exception at line 2525, column 4 in http://localhost:52288/Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.js

0x80020003 - JavaScript runtime error: Member not found.
```

I obviously have an issue somewhere with jquery-1.8.3.js, but I'm rather new to this and have no idea where to begin. Could someone point me in the right direction? Here's the function where it's failing.

```
if ( !getSetAttribute ) {

    fixSpecified = {
        name: true,
        id: true,
        coords: true
    };

    // Use this for any attribute in IE6/7
    // This fixes almost every IE6/7 issue
    nodeHook = jQuery.valHooks.button = {
        get: function( elem, name ) {
            var ret;
            ret = elem.getAttributeNode( name );
            return ret && ( fixSpecified[ name ] ? ret.value !== "" : ret.specified ) ?
                ret.value :
                undefined;
        },
        set: function( elem, value, name ) {
            // Set the existing or create a new attribute node
            var ret = elem.getAttributeNode( name );
            if ( !ret ) {
                ret = document.createAttribute( name );
                elem.setAttributeNode( ret );
            }

                          // FAILING ON THIS LINE
            return ( ret.value = value + "" );  // <--- ?
        }
    };

    // Set width and height to auto instead of 0 on empty string( Bug #8150 )
    // This is for removals
    jQuery.each([ "width", "height" ], function( i, name ) {
        jQuery.attrHooks[ name ] = jQuery.extend( jQuery.attrHooks[ name ], {
            set: function( elem, value ) {
                if ( value === "" ) {
                    elem.setAttribute( name, "auto" );
                    return value;
                }
            }
        });
    });

    // Set contenteditable to false on removals(#10429)
    // Setting to empty string throws an error as an invalid value
    jQuery.attrHooks.contenteditable = {
        get: nodeHook.get,
        set: function( elem, value, name ) {
            if ( value === "" ) {
                value = "false";
            }
            nodeHook.set( elem, value, name );
        }
    };
}


// Some attributes require a special call on IE
if ( !jQuery.support.hrefNormalized ) {
    jQuery.each([ "href", "src", "width", "height" ], function( i, name ) {
        jQuery.attrHooks[ name ] = jQuery.extend( jQuery.attrHooks[ name ], {
            get: function( elem ) {
                var ret = elem.getAttribute( name, 2 );
                return ret === null ? undefined : ret;
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: provide your code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in IE10 compatibility mode. see [Bug #12577](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12577)

There was a microsoft connect bug for this as well but microsoft closed it as will not fix in IE10.

This is also a possible duplicate question of [jquery-script3-member-not-found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13462569/jquery-validation-plugin-ie7-script3-member-not-found) but i don't have enough rep to mark it as such.

Answer (score 2):

I just came across a solution that seems to work. I added the following line inside the  tag of my _Layout.cshtml.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE" />
```

Here's where I came across the solution:

http://twigstechtips.blogspot.com/2010/03/css-ie8-meta-tag-to-disable.html