# Not able to solve jquery IE 7/8 Script 3 Member not found error

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

My web app is running here: [URL](http://aquotebike.testquote.co.uk/brandlist)
I am using jquery version 1.7.1.min.js for ie browsers and I am getting the following error for IE 7 and 8.

Error details:

```
SCRIPT3: Member not found.

jquery-1.7.0.min.js, line 2 character 30982
```

I have also find that `e.nodeValue` is null as you can see in the attached image.[image]. However, the same code runs fine for IE 9 and 10.

While going through the code, I have found the below code which doesn't run for ie6/7. Any help how to get rid of this error?

```
/ IE6/7 do not support getting/setting some attributes with get/setAttribute
if ( !getSetAttribute ) {

    fixSpecified = {
        name: true,
        id: true
    };

    // Use this for any attribute in IE6/7
    // This fixes almost every IE6/7 issue
    nodeHook = jQuery.valHooks.button = {
        get: function( elem, name ) {
            var ret;
            ret = elem.getAttributeNode( name );
            return ret && ( fixSpecified[ name ] ? ret.nodeValue !== "" : ret.specified ) ?
                ret.nodeValue :
                undefined;
        },
        set: function( elem, value, name ) {
            // Set the existing or create a new attribute node
            var ret = elem.getAttributeNode( name );
            if ( !ret ) {
                ret = document.createAttribute( name );
                elem.setAttributeNode( ret );
            }
            return ( ret.nodeValue = value + "" );
        }
    };
```

Comment: can you please debug using debug file? It is not always accurate in the min version.

Comment: @OnurTOPAL I have just replaced the min.js code with debug version on the server.

Comment: Can this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993085/ie-9-showing-displaying-member-not-found

Comment: I have tried wrapping this if condition with try catch block, but no luck! so I have just made the condition `(!getSetAttribute)` to `(getSetAttribute)`. This dirty way works for now. But plz let me know how to actually sove this issue.

Comment: Did you try upgrading to jquery 1.11.1?

Comment: What's the type of the `ret`? [Docs say](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534192(v=vs.85).aspx) that it has to be a `TextNode` or an `attribute` for `nodeValue` to result in non-`null`. As it suggests check the `nodeName`.

Comment: If the error is caused by some feature missing in IE 6/7 you could try using modernizr: http://modernizr.com/

Answer (score 0):

Give up.

Don't support IE 7/8.  Why support a dying species?  [Google decided a long time ago that they'd only support the latest](http://googleforwork.blogspot.com/2011/06/our-plans-to-support-modern-browsers.html), why should you do any different?

Comment: This is not an sensible answer to my question. Its not my personal project to make browser support decisions. However, my trick above still works. I

Comment: This still happens with IE10/11 if page is from intranet and so IE falls back to IE7 document mode.