# Passing event object to debounced function in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, dom-events

I want to debounce a keyup event on a table of rows which causes an AJAX call. I have used all debouncing plugins out there, including the one for jQuery by Ben Alman, the one from Underscore.js, the jQuery `delayed()` plugin, as well as one plugin from Filatov Dmitry which extends jQuery (like Ben Alman's).

My code looks like this:

```
function onKeyUp(evt) {
    doSomethingWith(evt, true);
}

$('#mytable').on('keyup', $.debounce(500, onKeyUp));
```

The problem is that, while it works fine on Firefox and IE9, it doesn't work in IE8. Specifically, IE8 throws a "Member not found" error when I call `evt.preventDefault()` which goes into the jQuery 1.11.1 code and breaks in line 4967 on `e.returnValue = false;` (because `preventDefault()` apparently doesn't exist in IE8). Upon inspection of the event variable with the IE developer tools debugger, it seems that the variable contains all event member methods and properties, but most of them are marked as "Member not found".
I've alread tried this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/3533725/134120 but it did not work.
Googling for "IE member not found" returns a lot of results, but not many solutions.

So, any ideas?

Comment: Um, makes no sense to prevent default long after the event has finished. If you want to cancel the event, you will need to approach this differently.

Comment: It works as intended in Firefox and IE9, and I use preventDefault() successfully to prevent scrolling down or up with the arrow keys which is the default behaviour.

Comment: Why do you even need a plugin, this is easy to do yourself -> **http://jsfiddle.net/njeqmb0b/**

Comment: @AsGoodAsItGets: But for preventing all scroll events you wouldn't `debounce` the handler?

Comment: @Bergi I need to first prevent the default handler (i.e. no scrolling) and then debounce my event handler.

Comment: @AsGoodAsItGets: Yes, you need to do that. But that's not what the code you've posted does.

Comment: All the debounce plugins basically uses a timeout, so you can't prevent the event even if you pass it, as it's already happened when the timeout fires, see the fiddle I posted above. You have to prevent the default *before* you debounce, and you can check `e.which` to only prevent the arrow keys.

Comment: @adeneo I'm testing your code...

Comment: I think you're both right. It seems elementary (my dear Watson) but I guess this is another case of a brain not seeing the obvious (after too many hours of coding). @adeneo if you post this as an answer I will accept it because it indeed requires no plugin. Otherwise I will accept Bergi 's solution. Thank you both! :)

Comment: Just accept Bergi's answer if that helps you out, he needs the rep ;) ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to first prevent the default handler (i.e. no scrolling) and then debounce my event handler.

Then use this:

```
var onKeyUp = $.debounce(500, doSomethingWith);

$('#mytable').on('keyup', function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault(); // do always
    onKeyUp(evt, true); // possibly bounced call to doSomethingWith
});
```