# IE11 Throws 'Member not found' Error when handling SVG

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, svg, asp-classic, internet-explorer-8

I am currently working on fixing some bugs that have surfaced as a result of upgrading from IE8 to IE11. The function in which the error occurs attempts to set a variable to reference a SVG document. Names are then assigned to element attributes within the SVG. This code was working correctly in IE8, but is no longer working in IE11.

I am working in IE11 with Enterprise Mode enabled.

**Document mode:** 5
**Browser Profile:** Enterprise
**User agent string:** Default

**Error:** SCRIPT3: Member not found.

**Line where error is thrown:**

```
var svgDoc = document.embeds(0).getSVGDocument();
```

**Function w/ error:**

```
function addMouseHandlers()
{
    var svgDoc = document.embeds(0).getSVGDocument();
    //var svgDoc = document.embeds(0).contentDocument();

    var rgrElements = svgDoc.getElementsByTagName("rgr:ranger");
    //document.all.results.innerHTML = rgrElements.length + " rgr:ranger nodes found.";

    //var childNodeList = rgrElements.item(0).getChildNodes();
    var gParent = null;
    var idx = 0;
    var sub = "";
    var point = "";
    for (idx = 0; idx < rgrElements.length; idx++) {
        sub = "";
        point = "";

        gParent = rgrElements.item(idx).parentNode();
        if (rgrElements.item(idx).hasAttribute("substation")) {
            sub = rgrElements.item(idx).getAttribute("substation");
        }
        if (rgrElements.item(idx).hasAttribute("point")) {
            point = rgrElements.item(idx).getAttribute("point");
        }
        gParent.setAttribute('onmouseover', 'showPointInfo(\"' + sub + '\", \"' + point + '\")');
        //gParent.setAttribute('onmouseout', 'showPointInfo(\"\", \"\")');
    }
}
```

**addMouseHandlers() called from:**

```
function bodyLoaded()
{
    var scriptToRun;
    scriptToRun = "closeWaiter3 \"pic\"";
    //document.parentWindow.parent.execScript(scriptToRun, "VBScript");
    addMouseHandlers();
}

//bodyLoaded() called onload
<BODY BGCOLOR=BLACK onload="bodyLoaded()">
```

I have looked a several related posts, but have not been able to apply the solutions to my issue. This post: [Member not found IE error (IE 6, 7, 8, 9)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531751/member-not-found-ie-error-ie-6-7-8-9) explains that this is an issue due to IE not passing an event to another function if that function call is within a setTimeout. However the call stack for this function does not include any reference to 'setTimeout'. I have also tried to reference the SVG document using 'contentDocument' property without success.

I believe this may be an issue with how the initial function is called using 'onload' but I am unable to uncover what needs to be changed while debugging.

**Q:** Would someone be able to guide me on how I can debug this issue and find the root of the problem?

Edit: The SVG embed tag is set like this:

```
<embed src="<%=strPic%>" name="SVGEmbed" WIDTH="1024px" HEIGHT="647px"/>
```

Am I trying to reference the SVG document incorrectly?

Comment: Fundamentally, if you're using `setAttribute` to hook up event handlers, you're doing it wrong. Look at `addEventListener`. Do I know that's the problem? No. But it's the first thing I'd fix. If it doesn't fix it, an [MCVE](/help/mcve) would be the next step.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Would this issue with event handlers inhibit me from calling and referencing the SVG document within the embed element? I was able to reference the SVG doc using `getSVGDocument()` in IE8 without issue. Not sure why a disconnect exists now. @T.J.Crowder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the svg doc object was not being initialized in time for the `getSVGDocument()` call. Adding a `setTimeout` for the `addMouseHandlers()` function call alleviated this issue.

```
function bodyLoaded()
{
    var scriptToRun;
    scriptToRun = "closeWaiter3 \"pic\"";
    //addMouseHandlers();
    //Added the settimeout so, svg gets some time to initialize
    setTimeout('addMouseHandlers()', 1000);
}
```

Not sure what the differences are between IE8 and IE11 that would cause this issue. Would someone with a greater knowledge of IE be able to explain why this occurred?